# SQL 2 Dimension Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I would like to pivot 2 tables in MS SQL 2008, so that I retrieve a survey question with all available answers in a single row.

Table 1 is "Questions"

```
ID   Text
1    What is your gender
2    Are you married
3    What is your Ethnicity
```

Table 2 is available "Answers" for each question

```
ID   QuestionID   Text
1    1            Male
2    1            Female
3    2            Yes
4    2            No
5    3            Caucasian
6    3            African/Black
7    3            Hispanic
8    3            Asian
etc.
```

I would like the result of my query to look like this:

```
QuestionID  QuestionText             Ans1       Ans2            Ans3      Ans4
1           What is your gender      Male       Female          Null      Null
2           Are you married          Yes        No              Null      Null
3           What is your Ethnicity   Caucasian  African/Black   Hispanic  Asian
```

I have tried 10 different combinations of Pivot, CTE, and sub-query with no luck.

I should mention there is no "Answer Sequence" column (yet).  The real DB has over 200 questions and 700 answers that are subject to change at any time, so coding each value isn't practical.

Your insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `PIVOT` function to get this result.

If you know how many `answers` you will have for each `question`, then you can hard-code the values similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select q.id,
    q.text question,
    a.text answer,
    'Answer_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by q.id 
                                      order by a.id) as varchar(10)) col
  from questions q
  left join answers a
    on q.id = a.questionid
) src
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for col in (Answer_1, Answer_2,
             Answer_3, Answer_4)
) piv
order by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5293e/10)

But if you have an unknown number of answers for each question, then you will need to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Answer_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by q.id 
                                      order by a.id) as varchar(10))) 
                    from questions q
                    left join answers a
                      on q.id = a.questionid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, question, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select q.id,
                  q.text question,
                  a.text answer,
                  ''Answer_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by q.id 
                                                    order by a.id) as varchar(10)) col
                from questions q
                left join answers a
                  on q.id = a.questionid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(answer)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by id'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5293e/9)

The result for both queries is:

```
| ID |               QUESTION |  ANSWER_1 |      ANSWER_2 | ANSWER_3 | ANSWER_4 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    What is your gender |      Male |        Female |   (null) |   (null) |
|  2 |        Are you married |       Yes |            No |   (null) |   (null) |
|  3 | What is your Ethnicity | Caucasian | African/Black | Hispanic |    Asian |
```

Comment: Both solutions worked perfectly!!  I have up to 16 answers to go with my questions so the second method fits my situation better.  Thank you.